# Clojure binding of dynamic var not working as expected

Tags: clojure

From what I understand, setting a new binding on a dynamic var affects all functions called within that binding, and all functions called from those functions.

Why does the binding appear to be lost in the first example below?

```
(def ^:dynamic *out-dir* "/home/user")

(binding [*out-dir* "/home/dave"] (map #(str *out-dir* %) [1 2 3]))
; gives:    ("/home/user1" "/home/user2" "/home/user3")
; expected: ("/home/dave1" "/home/dave2" "/home/dave3")

(binding [*out-dir* "/home/dave"] (conj (map #(str *out-dir* %) [1 2 3]) *out-dir*))
; gives: ("/home/dave" "/home/dave1" "/home/dave2" "/home/dave3")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by lazyness - `map` returns a lazy sequence which is defined inside the binding but is evaluated outside. You need to force the evaluation from inside:

```
(binding [*out-dir* "/home/dave"] 
  (doall (map #(str *out-dir* %) [1 2 3])))
```

Comment: Ah, that's it. Was able to find some more in depth information about binding gotchas here: [link](http://cemerick.com/2009/11/03/be-mindful-of-clojures-binding/)

Comment: @DavidVail, note that things have improved since that blog post was written (just one month later, Clojure 1.1 introduced `bound-fn`).

Answer (score 4):

It's true that laziness and dynamic bindings can cause problems; however, abandoning laziness is not the only solution. If you wish to preserve laziness (or to use dynamic bindings with `pmap`), use [`bound-fn`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/bound-fn) or [`bound-fn*`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/bound-fn*).

```
(def ^:dynamic x 0)

=> (binding [x 3] (map #(+ x %) (range 10)))
;; (0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)

=> (binding [x 3] (map (bound-fn [y] (+ x y)) (range 10)))
;; (3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12)

=> (binding [x 3] (map (bound-fn* #(+ % x)) (range 10)))
;; (3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use Python-style generator functions available via `lazy-gen` and `yield` [from the Tupelo library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo#generator-functions-for-lazy-sequences-a-la-python):

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t] ))
(t/refer-tupelo)

(def ^:dynamic foo 1)

(dotest
  (let [result (binding [foo 3]
                 (lazy-gen
                   (doseq [x (range 3)]
                     (yield {:foo foo :x x})))) ]
    (println result)))

result => ({:foo 3, :x 0} 
           {:foo 3, :x 1}
           {:foo 3, :x 2})
```