# Dynamic var lost inside for

Tags: clojure

I have found this strange behavior whenever I mix up the `for` macro with dynamic vars and `binding`. In order to illustrate it, I have come up with this minimal example which I can run in any `lein repl` I invoke in my system:

```
(def ^:dynamic foo 1)

(binding [foo 2]
  (println foo)) ; => 2

(binding [foo 2]
  (for [x (range 1)]
    (println foo))) ; => 1
```

As you can see, when inside a `for`'s scope, the value of the dynamic var `foo` is lost and the original value is obtained. Should I report this as a bug? Or is there an explanation for the behaviour?

Comment: Note that you get different behavior if you don't run this in the repl. Without the repl, the lazy seq produced by `for` is never evaluated and `1` is never printed at all; only the `2` from the first `binding` is printed.

Comment: Another solution is to use Python-style generator functions as described in this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33500282/clojure-binding-of-dynamic-var-not-working-as-expected/44892296#44892296